# how to use multiple fonts in r plot axis-labels?

Tags: r, plot, fonts, axis-labels

I'm customizing the x axis labels of a plot. Each label contains several values and several characters, one of which ('x') should be italicized. This code works fine although the content of labels appears only in regular font:

```
df <- data.frame(sp=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), n=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
labels <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
labels[i] = paste(df$sp[i], '\n(x = ', df$n[i], ')', sep = '')
}
plot(df$n, df$sp, xaxt = 'n')
axis( 1, at = seq( 1, nrow(df) ), labels = labels)
```

How can I italize character `x`? This call to `substitute` for example doesn't work:

```
substitute(paste(df$sp[i], italic('\n(x = '), df$n[i], ')', sep = ''), list(df$sp=df$sp, df$n=df$n) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to call `axis` once for each label, and using `atop()` rather than `\n`

```
plot(df$sp, df$n, xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, at = 1:nrow(df), labels = rep("", nrow(df)))
labels <-sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
  axis( 1, at = i, line = 2, lty = 0, 
   labels = bquote(atop(.(as.character(df$sp[i])),.("(")~italic(x)~"="~.(i)~")")))
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do the trick. I wanted character x to be italized not `df$sp`

Comment: @SantiXGR OK - revised answer

Comment: Nearly there! However, this last piece of code `.(i~")` should include the value `.(df$n[i]~")` but this change doesn't work. It neither works `.(as.character(df$n[i]~")`

Comment: Got it. There was a problem with the parentheses `labels = bquote(atop(.(as.character(df$sp[i])),.("(")*italic(n)~"="~.(i)*")")))`.